# Search button event on the handset

Tags: android, search

I want to open a screen when use click @ search button on the handset... how can i know that search button is pressed over the handset ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read this:  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introducing-quick-search-box-for.html